# Using Shopify API to create new product/variant

Tags: api, shopify, product, new-operator, variant

Hi I need to use Shopify's API in order to perform the following procedure but have no clue where to start. I have tried looking online at tutorials but find them very confusing. Does anyone know where I can start, or who I could pay to complete this task please.

Shopify is limited to 100 variants and I am trying to sell a product by the linear metre. I would like for the API to generate on request a new (temporary) variant dependnig on what size the customer enters.

1 - Customer enters size in linear metres on the product page

2 - Customer clicks ADD TO CART

3 - API creates a new variant of the selected product, calculates it's price based on the selected product multiplied by the number of metres they have entered

4 - The new variant is added to the cart

5 - After an hour, the new variant must be deleted

Does anyone know where I can start with this please? I have played around with Postman and can generate a new variant using that, but have no idea where to put the code etc.

Thanks
Jon

Comment: It doesn't sound like a good idea. I suggest you to use properties https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/product-pages-get-customization-information-for-products/m-p/616525

Comment: Line Item Properties won't allow for custom pricing depending on quantity. Eg. If my customer needs 12.1 metres of product, the price needs to be 12.1 * baserate of product

Comment: Can't you make the quantity the smallest amount you can sell? Like 10cm. And you select 20 for 2 meters?

Comment: Agree with Fabio make the price of the smallest available unit then adjust a product template and repurpose the quantity box to an input selecting a length.

Comment: My items are priced at 1p short of the £ eg. £19.99 per metre. £19.99 * 0.1mtr (unit measurement) means I would need to sell each 10cm unit for £1.999 and Shopify only allows prices to two decimal places. So using your method won't allow my pricing system to work unfortunately.